# Changing the value of one variable affects the value of variable which was previously assigned to it

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am getting values returned from mongodb in docs in the below code

```
collection.find({"Stories._id":ObjectID(storyId)}, {"Stories.$":1}, function (e, docs) {

        var results = docs;
        results[0].Stories = [];
}
```

I am assigning the value of docs to results. Then i change one array in that results to an empty array. The problem i face is, if I change the value of results, the value of docs is also getting affected!!
How can i change value of `results[0]` alone?

A simple [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7bfc20v6/) link

Comment: [Related, maybe tenuous dupe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language) - `var results = docs;` isn't cloning the data.

Answer (score 0):

This is because in java-script array and object are mutable by nature.
If y is an object, the following statement will not create a copy of y:

```
var x = y;  // This will not create a copy of y.
```

The object x is not a copy of y. It is y. Both x and y points to the same object.

Any changes to y will also change x, because x and y are the same object.

You can use simply use of following solution:

In **Jquery**

```
    results = $.extend(true,{},docs);//For deep copy
    results = $.extend({},docs);//For shallow copy
    results = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(docs))
```

In **Javascript**

```
function clone(obj) {
       var target = {};
       for (var i in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
         target[i] = obj[i];
        }
       }
       return target;
      }

results = clone(docs);
```

Answer (score 0):

You  can change the value of 'results[0]' alone without effecting the 'docs' by using the scope concept. Try making the changes in a function rather than in an immediate line or at the same hierarchy.
I have written a sample [here at Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a5559bt8)
A few months back, I was experimenting on how the concept of pass by reference works in terms of Objects in JS. We have to note that the return type of ds.find() is a json.  [You can read my article here](http://eshwartechtalks.blogspot.com/2015/06/javascript-pass-by-value-and-pass-by.html)
Thanks.

```
var docs = [1,2,3];
var results = docs;
console.log(results[0]);


var documents =[ {
'stories':'eshwar',
'place':'Hyd'
},
            {
'stories':'Prasad',
'place':'Del'
},
            {
'stories':'Hari',
'place':'Chennai'
}]

console.log(documents[2]); //prints {stories: "Hari", place: "Chennai"}

function ChangeAlone(documents){
var refDoc = documents;
refDoc[2] =[];    
}
// the value of stories remains same in the parent object without change
console.log(documents[2].stories); //prints Hari
```